# Bookshelf withRelated ignoring foreignKey

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I'm trying to use bookshelf to return related rows by connected by a column called account_id. I previously had this all working fine when it was just linked by the 'id' column but then for one reason or another we had to change it to something different.

My bookshelf code looks something like this:

```
var Accounts = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'accounts',
  hasTimestamps: true,
  dailyTasks: function() {
    return this.hasMany(dailyTasks, 'account_id');
  }    
});

var dailyTasks = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'accounts_daily_tasks',
  hasTimestamps: true,
  account: function() {
    return this.belongsTo(Accounts, 'account_id')
  }
});
```

The tables schema looks like so:

**accounts**

```
|---------|----------------------------|
|    id   |  account_id (primary key)  |
|---------|----------------------------|
|    12   |       34                   |
|---------|----------------------------|
```

**accounts_daily_tasks**

```
|    id (primary key)   |  account_id   |
|-----------------------|---------------|
|    12                 |      34       |
|-----------------------|---------------|
```

Which indexes accounts table column account_id

And when I run the following:

```
Accounts.where('user_id', user_id).fetchAll({
                          withRelated: ['dailyTasks']
                        })
```

I get dailyTasks returned as empty. However in the database it is all hooked up.

When I debug I see it's calling this:

```
select `accounts_daily_tasks`.* from `accounts_daily_tasks` where `accounts_daily_tasks`.`account_id` in (1, 3, 4)' }
```

So the fact that it's searching `in (1,3,4)` tells me it is searching by the column called id rather than account_id. I feel like I've tried everything but just can't get this to work.

Comment: What's the schema of the 2 tables?

Comment: I edited the post and added the basic table schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure this out, I was missing 'idAttribute' in the accounts model. So I changed it to:

```
var Accounts = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'accounts',
  hasTimestamps: true,
  idAttribute: 'account_id',
  dailyTasks: function() {
    return this.hasMany(dailyTasks, 'account_id');
  }
});
```

And hey presto, it all works again.